# Keycloak Provider and JAX-RS Client?

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus, resteasy

I have the need to call a REST endpoint after a user account is created in Keycloak (specifically, Keycloak 22.x).  To accomplish this, I have implemented a Keycloak `EventListenerProvider` that listens for the appropriate event.  As a PoC I had my `EventListenerProvider` simply log the event.  Once I confirmed that was working, I started trying to use a JAX-RS Client Proxy to call my REST endpoint.  However, I'm getting some exceptions when making the call.  Here's what I've done...

My JAX-RS Client Proxy interface is built using Quarkus 3.2.4, simply because the rest of my code (and Keycloak, for that matter) uses Quarkus. It looks something like this:

```
@Path("/")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface MyClientProxy {

    @Path("/api/v1/admin/{realmIdentifier}/users/{userIdentifier}")
    @PUT
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response createUserProfile(@PathParam("realmIdentifier") String realmIdentifier,
            @PathParam("userIdentifier") String userIdentifier, CreateUserProfileRequest request);

}
```

From there, my `EventListenerProvider` instantiates the proxy as follows:

```
String baseURI = ...
UriBuilder ub = UriBuilder.fromPath(baseURI);
ResteasyClient client = (ResteasyClient) ClientBuilder.newClient();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(ub);

MyClientProxy proxy = target.proxy(MyClientProxy);
```

However, when my `EventListenerProvider` tries to call `createUserProfile` I see the following `Exception` in the Keycloak logs:

```
2023-08-23 18:43:16,929 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-5) Uncaught server error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found
```

My initial assumption is that Resteasy was not included.  My Maven build uses `maven-shade-plugin` to build a fat JAR, so I added an include line to ensure that `org.jboss.resteasy:*` would be included in the fat JAR.  That led to a different `Exception`, though:

```
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.resteasy.deployment.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep#staticInit threw an exception: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @e36bb2a wants to load interface org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment. A different interface with the same name was previously loaded by java.net.URLClassLoader @37c7595. (org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @37c7595, parent loader 'app')
```

I've never seen that one before, so I'm not sure what's going on here.  Any idea what could be the problem?  I'm sure I'm missing something minor, but I can't pin down what.

Comment: Can you try to use https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-admin-client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!  After modifying the `includes` statement for `maven-shade-plugin` everything works properly.  The new `includes` statement looks like this:

```
<includes>
  <include>org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client</include>
  <include>org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client-api</include>
</includes>
```

The `resteasy-client` classes are not present in Keycloak and were missing from my fat JAR.  After making this change I no longer ran into any problems.

Comment: I am running into the similar issue with my custom adapter that is based on latest keycloak version i.e. 22.0.4. When I have added this includes into my maven shade plugin, the fat jar is almost empty. Can you please share the full configuration of your shade plugin ?